# How to get a region of interest from a SWT Image?

Tags: java, swt

I want to get a region of interest (ROI) from an SWT Image object.

I am unable to find a method that will do this for me. Is it possible to avoid writing one by myself?

I need something like (similar to opencv implementations):

```
Image img = new Image(display, path);
Rectangle roi = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
Image imgRoi = img.getROI(roi);
```

Comment: Please explain, what is ROI?

Comment: Region of Interest

Comment: Don't assume people know about OpenCV, explain exactly what you want this method to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a base SWT method to create images from a region, but I found a snippet that should do that here https://gist.github.com/azhawkes/4347761 (credits goes to the author Andy Hawkes).

Here I slightly modified the method to get in input the original image. I also implemented an optimization suggested by [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055297/how-to-get-a-region-of-interest-from-a-swt-image#comment71296929_42056243) (minimized the calls to `Image.getImageData`).

```
public static Image loadImageFromRegion(Image original, Rectangle region) {

    ImageData originalImageData = original.getImageData();

    ImageData data = new ImageData(region.width, region.height, originalImageData.depth, originalImageData.palette);
    int[] pixels = new int[region.width];
    byte[] alphas = new byte[region.width];

    for (int y = 0; y < region.height; y++) {
        originalImageData.getAlphas(region.x, region.y + y, region.width, alphas, 0);
        originalImageData.getPixels(region.x, region.y + y, region.width, pixels, 0);

        data.setPixels(0, y, region.width, pixels, 0);
        data.setAlphas(0, y, region.width, alphas, 0);
    }

    return new Image(Display.getCurrent(), data);
}
```

Comment: `Image.getImageData` is an expensive operation. Calling it multiple times like this will make the code much slower than it needs to be.